# python cx_oracle hang when storing as DataFrame?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I'm trying to store the results of an Oracle SQL query into a dataframe and the execution hangs infinitely. But, when I print the query it comes out instantly. What is causing the error when saving this as a DataFrame?

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('HOST', 'PORT', service_name='SID')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='USER', password='PASSWORD', dsn=dsn_tns)
curr =conn.cursor()
curr.execute('alter session set current_schema= apps')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from TABLE', curr)
####THE ALTERNATIVE CODE TO PRINT THE RESULTS
# curr.execute('select * from TABLE')
# for line in curr:
#     print(line)
curr.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas's [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) requires a connection object for its *con* argument not the result of a cursor's `execute`. Also, consider using [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html) the recommended interface between pandas and databases where you define the schema in the engine connection assignment. This engine also allows [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) calls.

```
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@host:port/dbname")

df = pd.read_sql('select * from TABLE', con=engine)

engine.dispose()
```

And as mentioned on this [DBA post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37022), in Oracle users and schemas are essentially the same thing (unlike other RBDMS). Therefore, try passing *apps* as the user in `create_engine` call with needed credentials:

```
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://apps:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/SID")

df = pd.read_sql('select * from TABLE', con=engine)

engine.dispose()
```